# How to repair anchor holes and re-mount bathroom tissue dispenser

Tags: drywall

I need to repair the holes where tissue bracket was installed, then re-mount it. About 3 inches behind the drywall are bricks. I thought about re-mounting it with 1 inch toggle bolts after repairing the holes with drywall tape.

Answer (score 1):

If you  are repairing the wall and re-installing the tissue dispenser it would be wise to "multi-task" the repair.

Cut the damaged area to an opening smaller than the length of the dispensers screw holes. Cut a piece of 1/2 or 3/4 inch plywood 2 inches longer and slightly narrower than the cut you just made. Secure the plywood into the wall incision so that it will be held in place by a screw at each end of the wall opening (the plywood should extend an equal distance behind the drywall).

The newly installed plywood can now be used to attach a drywall plug and then the dispenser.

Comment: Any criticism for the down vote? No one wants to explain? Just like to remain anonymous?

Comment: idk, but Iggy didn't deserve *two* of them. Especially since it's the answer closest to removing the *how to* from the OP's title, that once removed answers itself: *repair anchor holes and re-mount bathroom tissue dispenser* - idk what's so hard about that if you know how to patch drywall, and install wall anchors.

Answer (score 0):

It is going to be faster and hold longer if you cut drywall to studs and add a new piece of drywall in.  You will need less mud/tape and you won't worry about the expansion of the bricks pushing on the drywall/material - if you decided to just fill the space - which would probably show after time if not done right.

Answer (score 0):

Go with your initial plan, unless people are using the dispenser as a grab-bar. If they're just old anchor screws holes of the 1/4" round about size, yank out the old anchors with needle nose pliers or send them through the drywall by palming or hammering a Phillips head screw driver (as big as the anchor's full face diameter) into the anchors. If you're re-mounting in the same spot then toggles should do great & vastly better than any in-drywall anchor...go with as big a toggle as will fit the dispenser or use what you have & just re-do it down the road if they were too small to hold up. I'm assuming the dispenser would cover any ugliness of hole enlargement. If you're re-locating, go at least 3" away from the old holes with your toggles & just fill the old holes a couple of times with compound for primer & paint.